# Is it possible to share my page into specific group or page in facebook Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have facing a problem in my project. Suppose I have 3 groups of in my facebook account. I want to share my blog post or page into specific group.  Is it possible? I am using laravel for this. Please help me.

After googling I only find to share post in facebook using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".modal_share .shareNow").click(function () {
            var shareUrl = $.trim($(this).attr("data-url")).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            window.open(shareUrl, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this is for my facebook wall. Also all controls manage by facebook in here I can choose the group, message to share my bolg. But the control and functionality  is done facebook. I only called. But is it possible to share it specific group or page in facebook.

Comment: no php sdk code, no laravel/php code, this is a general question so i have removed the unrelated tags. also, your question is way too broad for stackoverflow, please add what you have tried so far (research, code for testing, debug info, ...)

Comment: @luschn I am not trying anything. I don't know is it possible or not. Also i added laravel tag because i want to implement this using laravel

Comment: @luschn also i am updated my question. plz take a look

Comment: on stackoverflow, you are required to try stuff on your own first. it´s what developers do, right? please check out the api docs. if you want to get a finished solution without knowing the details, you better hire a developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement Facebook Graph API to login to your Facebook App in Laravel then you can post to Facebook Groups that you manage.

You can obtain Facebook Group IDs that you manage using the following Facebook Graph API(See Reading):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

Once you have Facebook Group IDs that you manage, you can post on your groups by using the following Facebook Graph API (See Publishing):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/group/feed